# Add rows, if missing, in order to keep desired sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Hcode |  Hname | ctry | value
  1   |   a    |  X   |  34
  2   |   b    |  X   |  45
  1   |   a    |  Y   |  46
  2   |   b    |  Y   | 123
  3   |   c    |  Y   | 343
  1   |   a    |  Z   | 314
  2   |   b    |  Z   |  12
```

I would like to have for each `'ctry'` the same number of rows. That is, each `'ctry'` would have an `Hname` row for `a`, `b`, and `c` -- regardless of whether there is an associated value for that given row.

What I am after is something like this:

```
Hcode |  Hname | ctry | value
  1   |   a    |  X   |  34
  2   |   b    |  X   |  45
  3   |   c    |  X   |  
  1   |   a    |  Y   |  46
  2   |   b    |  Y   | 123
  3   |   c    |  Y   | 343
  1   |   a    |  Z   | 314 
  2   |   b    |  Z   |  12
  3   |   c    |  Z   |
```

To make things slightly more complicated, my `Hname` column consists of 200 values, e.g. a,b,c,...,200.

I have an Excel file with all 200 rows of `Hcode` and `Hname` values.

How can I insert these additional rows, which will contain blank values in the `value` column, using the information stored in my Excel file?

**EDIT**:

@piRSquared response worked great for the above. But I tried to generalize and add to the code using a larger dataset and I ran into the following error `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`.

My expanded dataset looks like this:

```
Hcode |  Hname | Hcateg | ctry | ctry_code | region| region_code| v1 | v2 
  1   |   a    |   A    |  X   |   XX      | AFR   |  1         | 34 |  5
  2   |   b    |   B    |  X   |   XX      | AFR   |  1         | 45 | 12
  1   |   a    |   A    |  Y   |   YY      | EUR   |  2         |    | 10
  2   |   b    |   B    |  Y   |   YY      | EUR   |  2         | 78 | 95
  3   |   c    |   C    |  Y   |   YY      | EUR   |  2         | 25 | 29
  1   |   a    |   A    |  Z   |   ZZ      | MAR   |  3         |    | 59 
  2   |   b    |   B    |  Z   |   zz      | MAR   |  3         | 98 | 75
```

Note that `Hcode` always corresponds to the same `Hname` and `Hcateg`. Same applies to `ctry` and `ctry_code`. And again the same applies to `region` and `region_code`.

My attempt:

```
cols = ['Hcode', 'Hname', 'Hcateg', 'ctry', 'ctry_code', 'region',
         'region_code']

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    h + (c,)
    for c in df['ctry'].unique()
    for h in pd.factorize([*zip(df['Hcode'],
                                df['Hname'],
                                df['Hcateg'],
                                df['ctry_code'],
                                df['region'],
                                df['region_code'],)])[1]
                    ], columns=cols)

df2.merge(df, 'left')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dataframe to merge with

```
cols = ['Hcode', 'Hname', 'ctry']
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    h + (c,)
    for c in df.ctry.unique()
    for h in pd.factorize([*zip(df.Hcode, df.Hname)])[1]
], columns=cols)

df2.merge(df, 'left')

   Hcode Hname ctry  value
0      1     a    X   34.0
1      2     b    X   45.0
2      3     c    X    NaN
3      1     a    Y   46.0
4      2     b    Y  123.0
5      3     c    Y  343.0
6      1     a    Z  314.0
7      2     b    Z   12.0
8      3     c    Z    NaN
```

---

#### Generalized

```
hcols = ['Hcode', 'Hname', 'Hcateg']
ccols = ['ctry', 'ctry_code', 'region', 'region_code']

H = {*zip(*map(df.get, hcols))}
C = {*zip(*map(df.get, ccols))}

d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [h + c for h in H for c in C],
    columns=hcols + ccols
)

d2.merge(df, 'left')

    Hcode Hname Hcateg ctry ctry_code region  region_code    v1    v2
0       2     b      B    X        XX    AFR            1  45.0  12.0
1       2     b      B    Y        YY    EUR            2  78.0  95.0
2       2     b      B    Z        ZZ    MAR            3   NaN   NaN
3       2     b      B    Z        zz    MAR            3  98.0  75.0
4       1     a      A    X        XX    AFR            1  34.0   5.0
5       1     a      A    Y        YY    EUR            2  10.0   NaN
6       1     a      A    Z        ZZ    MAR            3  59.0   NaN
7       1     a      A    Z        zz    MAR            3   NaN   NaN
8       3     c      C    X        XX    AFR            1   NaN   NaN
9       3     c      C    Y        YY    EUR            2  25.0  29.0
10      3     c      C    Z        ZZ    MAR            3   NaN   NaN
11      3     c      C    Z        zz    MAR            3   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks. How can I modify the code to include the following: I have two columns that coincide in every row (i.e. `ctry` and `ctry_code`) and I also seven columns with values: `value 1`, `value 2`, ..., `value7`.

Comment: If you feel that the added complexity equates to the same question, add an example to the post and inform me when you have.  Otherwise, ask a new question and finalize this one by accepting an answer if one satisfies the conditions you've laid out in your question.

Comment: thanks again for your help. I added an edit to my question above. I feel like it's sufficiently related to my original question that an edit would be enough (let me know if you think otherwise). Again, your help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: See if that suffices.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. I ran it and no errors, however, the `v1` and `v2` values do not appear in the resulting `d2` dataframe.

Comment: They shouldn't.  They should appear in the result of the merge `d2.merge(df, 'left')`  To persist the result, assign it to a name `d3 = d2.merge(df, 'left')`

Answer (score 0):

To create a row for each `ctry`, for each value of `Hname`, you can transform your DataFrame to have `Hname` as the columns with `unstack`, and then re-stack your data, preserving the blank values:

```
df.set_index(["ctry", "Hname"])["value"].unstack().stack(dropna=False)
```